# Unity 3D Collisiondetection

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-physics

I generate an Gameobjct array of speheres and try to apply a collider to them to detect collision with my character controller.

i tried serverel methods, nothing worked. Why Unity doent detect the collision ?

Script for generating the array :

```
 public GameObject[] Chunkzufall(float l, float b, int n)
{
    GameObject chunk = new GameObject();
    GameObject[] chunks = new GameObject[n];

    chunkSpeed = new float[n];
    chunkMaxH = new float[n];
    chunkMinH = new float[n];

    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        float h = 1;
        float posX = Random.Range(0.0f, b);
        float posZ = Random.Range(0.0f, l);

        GameObject group = Chunk(h);
        group.transform.Translate(posX, 0.0f, posZ);

        group.transform.parent = chunk.transform;
        chunk.tag = "reset";
        chunk.name = "chunk";

        chunkSpeed[j] = (float) Random.Range(-0.04f, 0.04f);
        chunkMaxH[j] = (float) Random.Range(2.0f, 10.0f);
        chunkMinH[j] = (float) Random.Range(-2.0f, -10.0f);

        chunk.AddComponent<SphereCollider>();
        chunk.GetComponent<SphereCollider>().isTrigger = true;
        chunk.GetComponent<SphereCollider>().radius = 5.0f;

        chunks[j] = chunk;

    }
    return chunks;
}

public void MoveChunks(GameObject[] chunks)
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach(GameObject chunk in chunks)
    {
        Vector3 position = chunk.transform.GetChild(i).position;

        if (position.y >= chunkMaxH[i] || position.y <= chunkMinH[i])
        {
            chunkSpeed[i] = chunkSpeed[i] * -1;
        }

        position.y = position.y - chunkSpeed[i];
        chunk.transform.GetChild(i).position = position;
        chunk.GetComponent<SphereCollider>().center = position;

        i++;
    }
    i = 0;
}
```

collision trigger function :

```
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col) {
    if(col.gameObject.tag == "reset") {
        transform.position = new Vector3(startX, startY, startZ);
        Debug.Log("chunk");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Lazy Male I believe [this post](https://answers.unity.com/questions/187684/moving-object-with-transformposition-ignore-other.html) explains what you are facing and the caveats of “teleporting” object by updating _transform_. Hope setting the *velocity* helps :)

Comment: you should really build a prefab and save you some code... but anyway. add rigidbody to your `chunks` as well, i assume your player has a rigidbody attached? this should clear up the collision problems. if not  i dont really see any children attached to chunk:  * Vector3 position = chunk.transform.GetChild(i).position;*

Answer (score 3):

To detect a trigger on the dynaimcally created object, you have to enable the `IsTrigger` flag, add collider to the object. The object must also have `Rigidbody` attached to it. It looks like you already have the `IsTrigger`  flag and a collider but you are missing `Rigidbody`.

Replace this:

```
chunk.AddComponent<SphereCollider>();
chunk.GetComponent<SphereCollider>().isTrigger = true;
chunk.GetComponent<SphereCollider>().radius = 5.0f;
```

with

```
chunk.AddComponent<SphereCollider>();
chunk.AddComponent<Rigidbody>(); //ADDS RIGIDBODY COMPONENT
chunk.GetComponent<SphereCollider>().isTrigger = true;
chunk.GetComponent<SphereCollider>().radius = 5.0f;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `Rigidbody` attached? The objects need `Rigidbody` attached to it to be able to detect collision. And do note that for each pair of collider and collided objects, having one of them with `Rigidbody` attached is enough to capture the event. In your case, if you don't want to process the collision betweens spheres, then attach `Rigidbody` to your character object is good enough.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `RigidBody` to all of the spheres but that would be very inefficient if you want to have many of them. It is enough to have 1 `RigidBody` for every 2 objects that you want to check collision against.

So in your case it would be enough to put a `RigidBody` component on your character controller object.

Also, make sure the `RigidBody` is not set to Kinematic.